# How to share constants from one component with another in custom hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to build a custom hook to fetch data.

This is my *App.js*:

```
const [loadData, mainCategories] = useCustomHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={mainCategories}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

This is my *useCustomHook.js*:

```
const useCats = () => {
  const [mainCategories, setMainCategories] = useState();

  const loadData = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(
      `URL/read.php`
    );
    let results = await response.json();
    setMainCategories(results.data);
  };

  return [loadData, mainCategories];
};

export default useCustomHook;
```

It''s working fine. I'm returning and exporting `loadData` and `mainCategories` from my *useCustomHook.js* and I'm getting both in *App.js* to use it there.

Now comes the part I'm struggling with:

Let's say I need a constant from *App.js* in the *useCustomHook.js*. In my case I'm getting an ID in *App.js* (forwarded by react-navigation from the previous screen) which I need in the URL like so:

`URL/read.php?id=${id}`

Is there any way to get that ID in *useCustomHook.js*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as a parameter. Try below

```
const useCats = () => {
  const [mainCategories, setMainCategories] = useState();

  const loadData = async (id) => {
    let response = await fetch(
      `URL/read.php?id=${id} `
    );
    let results = await response.json();
    setMainCategories(results.data);
  };

  return [loadData, mainCategories];
};
```

Comment: It still not passed to useCustomHook.js If I console.log(id) it says: undefined

Comment: What is happening when you call `loadData('someId')`?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I had a typo in the useEffect hook. 

useEffect(() => {
    loadData(id);
  }, []);

I guess I can also pass a dependency in the useEffect hook in []? Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.